# Rstudio won't push to Github branch main

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I am struggling with Github and Rstudio. I don't know Github very well and I find the commands very confusing.

I read that Github preferred default branch should now be main and not master anymore. So I created my repository and followed instructions for creating a main branch.

**First question**:
do I need to use main as default branch to create an R package for download? I see that `devtools::install_github` still has master as default, so I am puzzled because Hadley and his group are usually very reliable.

I set Rstudio both local and origin to main. However, no matter what I do, Rstudio will always push to master (and recreate it if I deleted it) with the command `push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master`. (why is this command using HEAD:refs... and not just push origin master? If this is the problem, how do I change Rstudio's default?)

I tried `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/main` from bash to no avail. I can push to main manually with `git push origin main` but then Git starts nagging that master is behind. This command really pissed off git `git config --global push.default main`.

**Second question**:
How do I set Rstudio to push to main (or to both master and main)?

Comment: What version of `devtools` are you using? The latest version should use whatever the default branch name is. What exactly are you doing to trigger the push? Maybe this guide will help: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/07/5-steps-to-change-github-default-branch-from-master-to-main/

Comment: Hi. I have version 2.3, i see there is 2.4 now. I'll update, thanks. I had seen that post, but as i said, the suggested command `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/main' doesn't work for me.   I simply use commit + push from the rstudio "Git" panel (choosing main from the dropdown menu)

Comment: it is perfectly acceptable to use master, github may assume you are racist but rationale people will not

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. LOL. I thought the problem was connected with computeree slave-master jargon, I had never thought of the other side of it. then I definitely shouldn't use master :-)